# How can I share a screen over a flaky connection?

Tags: vnc, screen-sharing, ichat

Note: both parties are on Macs.

I'm trying to set up screen sharing between two computers, one located in Indiana and one located in Washington state.  We've tried using Messages (formerly iChat), which offers a screen-sharing feature which (as I understand it) is basically a wrapper around VNC.  However, the connection seems to drop periodically, which is a real nuisance.

Streaming video and similar applications are fine on both machines, so I don't think there's a major connectivity problem.

Is there anything that can be done to reduce the risk of dropped connections?  For instance, are there settings I should check in the Messages app, or is there another program we could use that would give us screensharing and voice functionality but has better error compensation than Messages?

Comment: I would concentrate first on the connection speed and quality.  Specifically in this case the upstream connection is more interesting since that is most likely where the constraint will be.

Comment: Okay, I can believe that, but this seems to be just restating the question.  As a screensharing neophyte, I don't know what I can do to improve the upload speed at either end.  Googling "troubleshoot dropped connection" and "troubleshoot upload speed" yielded only a bunch of vendor-specific help pages.  Are there some steps you can recommend to explore this issue?

Comment: yea... go to www.speedtest.net and run that speed test (watch out the ads on that page like to make you push the wrong button--wait for it and press "begin test"), then go to speakeasy.net/speedtest and run a couple more to different cities.    Let use know what you are seeing UPSTREAM from both sides of the connection.  Also you might try using skype screenshare and see if you have any better luck out of the box (at least just for test or comparison purposes, and you do not need a paid skype account the free is fine)